# Android TextView linespacing

Tags: android, textview

How to set the line spacing of TextView to 0?
I have tried:

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp";
```

But it dosen't work, I know set the value to negtive will solve this problem
Is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
android:lineSpacingExtra
```

and

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier
```

in your XML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
```

If the gap is still big use a smaller value than `0.8`.

Answer (score 0):

also use

```
 android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

from code you can use textView.setLineSpacing() or from xml you can use android:lineSpacingExtra